# Error in configuration process,projects files may be invalid error when building Opencv 3.1.0 and Opencv_Extra_module for Android from source?

Tags: android, mingw-w64, opencv3.1, cmake-gui

I am building Opencv 3.1.0 and Opencv_Extra_module for Android from source using the following procedures using CMake and mingw

1. start cmake-gui and select the opencv source code folder and the folder where binaries will be built (the 2 upper forms of the interface)
2. Press the Add Entry button and set Name=ANDROID_NDK select path and add the ndk directory to value
3. press the `configure` button. I choose the Specify toolchain for cross-compiling. Press Next and specify the toolchain file and i set to C:/Users/The/Documents/opencv-master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake. Press finish it builds fine but there are two many reptitive warning

   i) CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/CMake/share/cmake 3.7/ Modules/CMakeForce   Compiler.cmake:69 (message):The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated.  Instead just set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.

   ii) CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/ CMakeForce Compiler.cmake:83 (message):The CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER macro is deprecated.  Instead just set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
4. To compile the Opencv Extra module set the OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\Users\The\Downloads\opencv_contrib-master\modules
5. press the `configure` button for the second time but here is the error occuring Error in configuration process,projects files may be invalid  error occured on this stage.

   Please help me guys I have been searching for two days on how to build opencv and its extra module for android i asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060740/how-to-build-opencv-3-1-0-android-sdk-from-source-with-non-free-module)  question no one answered it?